# What is the difference between "change" and "unstitch"?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, word-choice, word-usage, synonyms

I'm English learner. As what the dictionary defines "unstitch" means *to change, spoil, or destroy something that has existed or been done previously.*
**Example:** In two years she has unstitched almost every aspect of the business and re-fashioned it.

Can I replace "unstitch" by the word "change"? Will it make any difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, "to unstitch" is used figuratively. "To unstitch", in its literal sense, is used to express the action of taking the stitches (the thread/cotton joining parts of a garment) out of a garment. This, of course, reduces the garment to its component parts. So "to unstitch" means "to take apart" - "to take apart" differs from "to change".